# Find all possible combinations of nested arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion, combinatorics

Let's say, I have an array of numbers and arrays, and I want flatten it:

```
[1, [2, [3]] -> [1, 2, 3]
```

it's easy. Now, let's say, I want to find all possible combinations, such that, at any point,

```
[a, [b, c]] -> [[a, b], [a, c]]
```

I'm struggling with supporting unpredictable and possible high order of complexity in this structure:

```
[1, [2, [3, 4]], [3, [4, [5, 6]], [7]] -> [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [1, 3, 7]
```

So it's definitely map/reduce-able problem, but I just can't wrap my head around it.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: that's a very interesting question, but it would be nice to check if you tried something already :D

Comment: Please check the example you provided again! It doesn't make much sense. (why `1` is included in `[1, 3, 4, 5]`?)

Answer (score 1):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach and collect all parts and push only if no array is found in the actual iterated array.

```js
function combine(array) {
    var result = [];
    array.forEach(function iter(r, p) {
        return function (a, _, aa) {
            if (Array.isArray(a)) {
                a.forEach(iter(r, p + 1));
                return;
            }
            r = r.slice(0, p);
            r[p] = a;
            aa.some(Array.isArray) || result.push(r);
        };
    }([], 0));
    return result;
}

console.log(combine([1, [2, [3]]]));                           // [[1, 2, 3]]
console.log(combine(['a', ['b', 'c']]));                       // [["a", "b"], ["a", "c"]]
console.log(combine([1, [2, [3, 4]], [3, [4, [5, 6]], [7]]])); // [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 3, 4, 5], [1, 3, 4, 6], [1, 3, 7]]
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a perfectly defined question but from the given data I could come up with the following answer which works just fine for the provided input set and should do OK for the implied combination logic behind the question.

```js
var  arr = [1, [2, [3, 4]]],
     brr = [1, [2, [3, 4]], [3, [4, [5, 6]], [7]]],
flatNest = (a,p = []) => a.reduce((r,e,i,b) => Array.isArray(e) ? Array.isArray(b[i-1]) ? r.concat(flatNest(e,p))
                                                                                        : r
                                                                : Array.isArray(b[i+1]) ? (r.push(...flatNest(b[i+1],[e]).map(f => p.concat(f))),
                                                                                           p.push(e),
                                                                                           r)
                                                                                        : (r.push(p.concat(e)),
                                                                                           r), []);
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatNest(arr)));
console.log(JSON.stringify(flatNest(brr)));
```